# Linked Server as Database

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, linked-server

I successfully created a linked postgresql server in SQL Server 2008. I can also query results using

```
 SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(POSTGRES32,'SELECT * FROM public.categories')
```

Is there a way to treat that linked server (Postgresql) as a SQL Server database?

Comment: It sounds like you want to *proxy* requests to PostgreSQL through MS-SQL, right? So an MS-SQL client connects to MS-SQL and MS-SQL sends every request on to PostgreSQL? If so, I doubt it's supported, but it wouldn't be very useful anyway. It'd fail if a client used any Ms-SQL specific syntax or features, like `SELECT [id] FROM [mytable];` non-standard quoting. So what you need is a bunch of views over queries, and/or procedures that run remote queries. Joins on the Ms-SQL side will perform very badly as it must fetch all data from both joined tables. Not a good idea.

Comment: The reason why im doing this is to connect postgres into ibm cognos 8 via mssql, so its impossible. Im a newbie in this matter, thanks

Comment: I sincerely doubt you will find any way to make that work. If it expects MS-SQL, it will use MS-SQL syntax, functions, etc. You can't just reroute that to PostgreSQL transparently. Why would you even want to? What actual problem are you trying to solve? What's the goal of running Cognos on PostgreSQL? I'm a big PostgreSQL fan, but if you already have MS-SQL....